# Editing entries in database through datagridview on button click C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

After searching stackoverflow for hours I was able to find a great answer to an issue I was having.  Updating existing entries in an access database through the datagridview.  Using what I learned there I was able to commit an update to database successfully.  However I have found issue.  I can only make one update per application session.  After I make one successfully, all subsequent updates to not save to database.  I am hoping someone on the site can take a look at my code and help pin point where my issue is.  I have looked at it for a couple days to no avail.

**Code for editing**

```
 private void AssetForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ACCESSORIES DATA GRID VIEW
            this.accessoriesTableAdapter.Fill(this.fAMDatabaseDataSet.Accessories);
            con.Open();
            string accCommandText = "SELECT * from Accessories";
            accAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(accCommandText, con);
            OleDbCommandBuilder accCB = new OleDbCommandBuilder(accAdapter);
            accView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            accDT = new System.Data.DataTable();
            accAdapter.Fill(accDT);
            BindingSource accBS = new BindingSource();
            accBS.DataSource = accDT;
            accView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
            accView.DataSource = accBS;
            con.Close();
        }
```

**Button that commits back to database**

```
private void accEditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            accAdapter.Update(accDT);
            accView.Refresh();
            MessageBox.Show("Asset Updated Successfully.");
        }
```

Comment: In IO objects (e.g. 'FileStream'), calling 'Close()' also disposes the underlying resources.  It might be the same case with the OleDbDataAdapter.  So try making a new instance of it to see if that solves your problem.  IIRC, OleDb is slow compared to the native connections (e.g. SqlConnection, MySqlConnection, etc.), so you might want to think about changing it if you experience performance issues.

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense.  If I am closing the connection and I make a new change and click the button again, there is no open connection to the database.